# api_def.pb.h not found when building tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to build c++ [tensorflow example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) on windows and then i get the following error:

> fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/api_def.pb.h: No such file or directory

I checked and see that `api_def.pb.h` is missing in the directory. It's strange that I downloaded whole source code from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), which I think there should be nothing wrong with it since it's the official site. But then I realized that not only this file but all the requiring `.pb.h` files are missing. Such as `op_def.pb.h`, `function.pb.h`, `node_def.pb.h`, ...

Though I can manually search on google, download and add other files to the appropriate directory, but in this case, all the result for `api_def.pb.h` file is about including it, none is about the content of raw file.

My questions are:

- Where/How can I get this file ?
- What is the real problem behind these missing files ?

ps: I've done some projects with tensorflow on python, this is the first time I have to do it with C++.

Comment: To my knowledge, the `.pb.h` files are supposed to be generated from protobuf definitions, so it is expected that they are not directly in the downloaded source. You might be missing a step in the build process that generates these...

Comment: These files are generated by the compiler, so you do not need to have them beforehand (it is why they are not provided). Do you have any other error message?

Comment: @Chelmy88 yes, before I have this error message, I received the same about `op_def.pb.h`, `function.pb.h`, `node_def.pb.h` ... I visit some github sites and see that they have these files on there (these are also included somewhere in their code too). I also see that many github projects are including api_def.pb.h, but none of these have the raw file. I think it's strange. Maybe it's just not been committed ?

Comment: I would be surprise to have such a mistake in tensor flow repository, bur maybe the easiest is to ask on the git itself (you can probably open an issue there)

Comment: As indicated by others, those files are all generated during the building process. When everything goes fine, you can find them under `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core/framework`. There must be some error before those ones breaking the process. Make sure you have carefully followed the [build instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) and look for any other error messages so we can help you identify the problem.